# Create Reports with Oracle 6i and Batch Database change

Tags: oracle, batch-file, report, builder, reportbuilder

I automate our reports. The system is based on `ORACLE 6i`, so I use this batch command:

```
start /wait "Report" x:\orav60\bin\rwrun60 reportname userid=pos/pospos DESTYPE=file DESFORMAT=pdf PARAMFORM=NO BATCH=YES BLANKPAGES=NO Von_Monat=%monat% Bis_Monat=%monat%  DESNAME=path
```

Since we have several locations I would have to connect to different databases, how can I enter this in the batch command?

Comment: _" how can I enter this in the batch command?"_ you have to be more specific, as this is unclear.

Comment: it works, i get the reports as PDF-File. I need only a connection to other Databases, because, my location is my database. I have installed the Programms, that i need to run this on batch, thats important.

Comment: ok, so then you need to show how you connect to the other databases

Comment: thats my question, if the field database is null so they connect to my location, wehere i am sitting. But i want another databaseconnection. I have googeled the problem and cant find there anything

Comment: but that is not a programming related question and is better suited for [superuser](http://superuser.com)

Comment: Came here looking for a solution to a report issue in a windows bat file, and the usage of start /wait solved my problem. Hopefully I was able to answer your question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're connecting to various Oracle databases, I'd just change the userid parameter:

userid=pos/pospos**@tnsalias**

Or you can use an EZCONNECT string:

userid=pos/pospos**@hostname:1521/service-name**